# What's the meaning of 'char (*p)[5];'?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I'm trying to grasp the differences between these three declarations:

```
char p[5];
char *p[5];
char (*p)[5];
```

I'm trying to find this out by doing some tests, because every guide of reading declarations and stuff like that has not helped me so far. I wrote this little program and it's not working (I've tried other kinds of use of the third declaration and I've ran out of options):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <string.h>                                                             
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
                                                                                
int main(void) {                                                                
        char p1[5];                                                             
        char *p2[5];                                                            
        char (*p3)[5];                                                          
                                                                                
        strcpy(p1, "dead");                                                     
                                                                                
        p2[0] = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));                              
        strcpy(p2[0], "beef");                                                  
                                                                                
        p3[0] = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));                              
        strcpy(p3[0], "char");                                                  
                                                                                
        printf("p1 = %s\np2[0] = %s\np3[0] = %s\n", p1, p2[0], p3[0]);          
                                                                                
        return 0;                                                               
}
```

The first and second works alright, and I've understood what they do. What is the meaning of the third declaration and the correct way to use it?

Thank you!

Comment: Decoding declarations is my least favorite part of C and C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The third is a *pointer* to an array of 5 chars, whereas the second is an *array* of 5 pointers to char.

Imagine it like this:

```
________          _____________________
|0x7777| -------> | H | e | l | l | o |
|______|          |_0_|_1_|_2_|_3_|_4_|
    p             ^
                  |
                  0x7777
```

Whereas the second one looks like that:

```
   "abc"  "def"  "ghi"  "jkl"  "mno"
    ^      ^      ^      ^      ^
    |      |      |      |      |
____________________________________
|0x9999|0x7777|0x3333|0x2222|0x6666|
|___0__|___1__|___2__|___3__|___4__|
                  p
```

This is one of the cases where understanding the difference between pointers and arrays is crucial. An array is an object whose size is the size of each of its elements times the count, whereas a pointer is merely an address.

In the second case, `sizeof(p)` will yield `5 * the_size_of_a_pointer`.

In the third case, `sizeof(p)` will yield `the_size_of_a_pointer`, which is usually `4` or `8`, depending on the target machine.

Comment: The [clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) is a handy thing to know when you're messing with `C`.

Comment: I tried to use p3 allocating 5 chars and pointing p3 to those and it didn't work. It's not working like you said... Would you mind posting some example code or something clearer?

Comment: In the third case, sizeof(p3) is not yielding what you said, it's yielding 8, which is the size of a pointer in my machine.

Comment: @jpmelos: The third doesn't work because `p3` is an unitialised pointer and you are attempting to dereference it with the array subscript operator (`p3[0]`). You could do something like that: `p3 = &p1`.

Comment: @jpmelos: oops, yes, a typing mistake.

Comment: Thank you. But I posted an answer of my own after I understood it, which I think is much clearer.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pointer to an array of chars. It is explained in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html). In the future, when you don't understand a declaration, use [`cdecl`](http://www.cdecl.org/) or `cdecl(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your link to the C FAQ helped me greatly understanding this topic.

Answer (score 4):

```
char p[5];      // p is a 5-element array of char
char *p[5];     // p is a 5-element array of pointer to char
char (*p)[5];   // p is a pointer to a 5-element array of char
```

C declaration syntax is built around the types of *expressions*, not objects.  The idea is that the form of the declaration matches the form of the expression as it would appear in the code.

In the cases above, we're dealing with arrays.  In the first case, `p` is an array of `char`; to access a particular character value, we would simply index into the array:

```
val = p[i];
```

The type of the expression `p[i]` is `char`, thus the declaration of `p` is `char p[5]`.

In the next case, `p` is an array of pointers to char; to access the value, we index into the array and dereference the result:

```
val = *p[i];
```

Postfix operators like `[]` have a higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so the above is parsed as

```
val = *(p[i]);
```

The type of the expression `*p[i]` is `char`, thus the declaration of `p` is `char *p[5]`.

In the final case, `p` is a pointer to an array of char, so to access a char value we have to dereference the array pointer and then subscript into the result:

```
val = (*p)[i];
```

Because `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`, we have to use parentheses to explicitly group `*` with `p` (as opposed to `p[i]`).  Again, the type of the expression `(*p)[i]` is `char`, so the declaration of `p` is `char (*p)[5]`.

**EDIT**

Pointers to arrays show up in the following contexts:

1. You're explicitly taking the address of an N-dimensional array:

   ```
   int x[10];
   int (*px)[10] = &x;
   ```

   Note that while the expressions `x` and `&x` yield the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array), they have different *types* (`int *` vs `int (*)[10]`).
2. You're dynamically allocating an array-type object:

   ```
   int (*px)[10] = malloc(sizeof *px);
   ```
3. An N-dimensional array expression "decays" into a pointer to an (N-1)-dimension array:

   ```
   int x[10][20];
   foo(x);
   ...
   void foo(int (*px)[20]){...}
   ```

Comment: +1. Very good explanation! Thank you, really made it clear how to think about declarations!

Comment: In your edit, first context, you say `x` has type `int *` and `&x` has type `int (*)[10]`. You actually mean `x` has type `int [10]`, I guess?

Comment: @jpmelos: Since it isn't an operand to `sizeof` or `&`, `x` would decay to `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

```
char (*p3)[5];
```

actually declares a pointer to an array of 5 `char`. It means it should point to a pointer that points to an array of 5 `char`. It doesn't allocate 5 of anything, just a pointer, and it should point to something that points to 5 `char`.

So, the correct use is:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <string.h>                                                             
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             

int main(void) {                                                                
        char p1[5];                                                             
        char *p2[5];                                                            
        char (*p3)[5];                                                          

        strcpy(p1, "dead");                                                     

        p2[0] = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));                              
        strcpy(p2[0], "beef");                                                  

        p3 = &p1;                                                               

        printf("p1 = %s\np2[0] = %s\np3 = %s\n", p1, p2[0], *p3);               

        return 0;                                                               
}
```

If you want to access a single position of that p1 string using p3 to access it, you must do `(*p3)[2]`, for example. It'll access the third position. That is because you first must transform p3 into p1 (the `(*p3)` dereferences before doing the position arithmetics) and then access the third position of that address (pointed by the dereferenced pointer).

Comment: Great, you summarised my answer better :-)